# Configuring MySQL for SLURM

Tags: mysql, 22.10, slurm

I'm having problems getting SLURM (for job scheduling) to work with a MySQL database.  I was using [this](https://slurm.schedmd.com/accounting.html) as a reference, but perhaps I misunderstood something in it.  If someone can let me know what I've missed, that would be great...

This is SLURM 21.08 on Ubuntu 22.10.  I'm using MySQL 8.0.32 .

I previously had configured SLURM working with completion and accounting being stored in a file.  And it seemed to be working fine; the controller was up and I ran one or two jobs ok.

Then, I switched to MySQL.  My `/etc/slurm/slurm.conf` had these values updated:

```
 Job Completion Logging | MySQL
      JobCompLoc | slurm_complete_db
      JobCompHost | localhost
      JobCompPort | <blank>
      JobCompUser | slurm
      JobCompPass | ...some password...
 Job Accounting Storage | SlurmDBD
      AccountingStorageLoc | slurm_acct_db
      AccountingStorageHost | localhost
      AccountingStoragePort | <blank>
      AccountingStorageUser | slurm
      AccountingStoragePass | ...
      AccountingStoreFlags | job_script,job_env
```

And in `/etc/slurm/slurmdbd.conf`:

```
 AuthType=auth/munge
 DbdHost=xps8930
 DebugLevel=info
 StorageHost=xps8930
 StorageLoc=slurm_acct_db
 StoragePass=...
 StorageType=accounting_storage/mysql
 StorageUser=slurm
 LogFile=/var/log/slurm/slurmdbd.log
 PidFile=/run/slurmdbd.pid
 SlurmUser=slurm
```

I've created two MySQL databases, a user called "slurm", and grant privileges as follows:

```
CREATE DATABASE slurm_complete_db DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE
utf8_unicode_ci ;
CREATE DATABASE slurm_acct_db DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE
utf8_unicode_ci ;
CREATE USER 'slurm'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY '' ;
GRANT ALL ON slurm_complete_db.* TO 'slurm'@'%';
GRANT ALL ON slurm_acct_db.* TO 'slurm'@'%';
```

I confirmed using the "show engines" command that InnoDB support is enabled.

Since the databases are empty, I believe my next step ought to be configuring the database.  In `slurm.conf`, I called my ClusterName "personal".  So, I did this:

```
$ sacctmgr add cluster personal
sacctmgr: error: slurm_persist_conn_open_without_init: failed to open
persistent connection to host:localhost:6819: Connection refused
sacctmgr: error: Sending PersistInit msg: Connection refused
```

`slurm` and `slurmdbd` are running (SLURM and MySQL are on the same computer):

```
$ ps -aef | grep slurm
root        1407       1  0 09:42 ?        00:00:08 /usr/sbin/slurmd -D -s
root        1857       1  0 09:43 ?        00:00:03 /usr/sbin/slurmdbd -D -s
```

In `/var/log/slurm/slurmdbd.log`, I see this:

```
[2023-01-26T18:06:02.541] error: mysql_real_connect failed: 2003 Can't
connect to MySQL server on 'xps8930:3306' (111)
[2023-01-26T18:06:02.541] error: The database must be up when starting
the MYSQL plugin.  Trying again in 5 seconds.
```

In `/var/log/slurm/slurmctld.log`, I have this:

```
[2023-01-26T09:42:33.264] error: Configured MailProg is invalid
[2023-01-26T09:42:33.350] slurmctld version 21.08.5 started on cluster personal
[2023-01-26T09:42:36.121] error: slurm_persist_conn_open_without_init: failed to open persistent connection to host:localhost:6819:
Connection refused
[2023-01-26T09:42:36.121] error: Sending PersistInit msg: Connection refused
[2023-01-26T09:42:36.153] accounting_storage/slurmdbd:  clusteracct_storage_p_register_ctld: Registering slurmctld at port 6817 with slurmdbd
[2023-01-26T09:42:36.153] error: Sending PersistInit msg: Connection refused
[2023-01-26T09:42:36.154] error: Sending PersistInit msg: Connection refused
[2023-01-26T09:42:37.456] No memory enforcing mechanism configured.
[2023-01-26T09:42:39.924] error: mysql_real_connect failed: 2002 Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
[2023-01-26T09:42:39.924] fatal: You haven't inited this storage yet.
```

I'm not sure what I should do next or what steps I'm missing.  I guess between `slurmdbd` and `slurmctld`, I should focus on `slurmdbd` first?  Once it is working, then either `slurmctld` should come up and/or I can try to get it working.

Sorry for the long post!  Any advice would be appreciated!

PS:  The command `munge -n | unmunge` was successful.

Comment: Apparently, MySQL was up when you created the databases, but the `/var/log/slurm/slurmdbd.log` says it's down. What does `systemctl status mysql` say?

Comment: @Jos Thanks for the suggestion!  So, `systemctl status mysql` says it is active and I can confirm I can use `mysql -u root -p` to log in on the command-line.  Seems like the problem is with`slurmdbd` -- like I missed something...

Comment: If Slurm keeps saying MySql is down, it is either trying to reach the wrong server (xps8930) or the wrong port (3306).

Comment: One thing worth checking is which interface mysqld binds to - I think by default it is 127.0.0.1, and I see you are trying to connect to xps8930, which I guess is the address of the NIC? If so, then that's why it can't find your MySQL

Comment: @j4nd3r53n Thanks for the suggestion and sorry for the late follow-up.  I got distracted by other things and put this on the back burner.  But just solved it today.  Indeed, you were correct.  I guess I had `xps8930` (value returned by `hostname`) throughout my `/etc/slurm/*` configuration files and what worked for me was `localhost`.  Thank you!

Comment: @Jos Sorry for the really, really late follow-up!  At the time, it wasn't urgent, so i set it aside purely out of frustrating.  I kept telling myself, "But MySQL is running!".  But I needed to get back to it and just force myself to figure it out.  I wrote down what I did today as an answer -- hope it is useful to others.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting this problem aside for many months, I finally decided I needed to get this working.  Hope this information will help someone else trying to figure this out.

`hostname` returned `xps8930` and that was what I used when I was doing file-based accounting.  What I had to do was set these values instead (other values in the configuration files were not relevant to the problem).

In `/etc/slurm/slurm.conf`:

```
ClusterName=personal
SlurmctldPidFile=/run/slurm/slurmctld.pid
SlurmdPidFile=/run/slurm/slurmd.pid
AccountingStorageHost=localhost
AccountingStoragePass=/var/run/munge/munge.socket.2
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/slurmdbd
AccountingStorageUser=slurm
AccountingStoreFlags=job_script,job_env
JobCompHost=localhost
JobCompPass=<some MySQL password>
JobCompType=jobcomp/mysql
JobCompUser=slurm
##  Database defaults to slurm_jobcomp_db
#JobCompLoc=slurm_complete_db
```

In `/etc/slurm/slurmdbd.conf`:

```
AuthInfo=/var/run/munge/munge.socket.2
AuthType=auth/munge
DbdHost=localhost
DebugLevel=info
LogFile=/var/log/slurm/slurmdbd.log
PidFile=/run/slurm/slurmdbd.pid
SlurmUser=slurm
StorageHost=localhost
StoragePass=<same MySQL password as above, since it's the same user>
StorageType=accounting_storage/mysql
StorageUser=slurm
StorageLoc=slurm_acct_db
```

`AccountingStoragePass` in the first file has the same value as `AuthInfo` in the second file.  I suppose they can be left blank so that defaults could be used.  A 10-year old [posting](https://slurm-dev.schedmd.narkive.com/tWk34Cpo/accounting-error-with-mysql-not-slurmdbd-munge-encode-failed-failed-to-access-password) guessed that this might be a bug.  But the current [documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html) for `AuthInfo` says it is fine.

After starting up `slurmdbd` (`sudo service slurmdbd start`), `sacctmgr` could be run:

```
$ sudo sacctmgr add cluster personal
 Adding Cluster(s)
  Name           = personal
Would you like to commit changes? (You have 30 seconds to decide)
(N/y): y
$ sacctmgr list cluster
   Cluster     ControlHost  ControlPort   RPC     Share GrpJobs       GrpTRES GrpSubmit MaxJobs       MaxTRES MaxSubmit     MaxWall                  QOS   Def QOS 
---------- --------------- ------------ ----- --------- ------- ------------- --------- ------- ------------- --------- ----------- -------------------- --------- 
  personal                            0     0         1                                                                                           normal
```

Once that started up fine, I started up the `slurmctld` and `slurmd` services.  And, everything looks fine so far.

Ports, etc. were left as default.  And perhaps several values could have been omitted since the defaults seemed fine.

In short, what changed compared to what I had earlier:

- Using `localhost` in `slurmdbd.conf`
- And not putting a password in `AccountingStoragePass`.  Since it has "Pass", I assumed I had to put a password there.

Hope this is useful to others!