# Problem with start up of the SLURM controller daemon

Tags: mysql, services, 23.10, slurm

I'm trying to configure SLURM on an Ubuntu 23.10 system so that it uses MySQL via `slurmdbd`.  This is a continuation of an earlier question which I [solved](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452839/configuring-mysql-for-slurm/1496982) through somewhat random guessing...

The funny thing is that the SLURM controller (`slurmctld`) fails to start upon boot.  However, when I manually restart the service, it appears fine.

For example, if I type `sudo service slurmctld status` after booting, I see these messages:

```
Feb 03 17:10:26 mycomputer slurmctld[1682]: slurmctld: error: Sending PersistInit msg: Connection refused
Feb 03 17:10:26 mycomputer slurmctld[1682]: slurmctld: accounting_storage/slurmdbd: clusteracct_storage_p_register_ctld: Registering slurmctld at port 6817 with slurmdbd
Feb 03 17:10:26 mycomputer slurmctld[1682]: slurmctld: No memory enforcing mechanism configured.
Feb 03 17:10:27 mycomputer slurmctld[1682]: WARNING: MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Feb 03 17:10:27 mycomputer slurmctld[1682]: slurmctld: error: mysql_real_connect failed: 2002 Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
Feb 03 17:10:27 mycomputer slurmctld[1682]: slurmctld: fatal: You haven't inited this storage yet.
Feb 03 17:10:27 mycomputer systemd[1]: slurmctld.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 03 17:10:27 mycomputer systemd[1]: slurmctld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

which is similar to the information in the `/var/log/` log file.  However, if I restart it with `sudo service slurmctld restart`, without changing any configuration files, it starts up with this in the log:

```
Feb 03 23:22:57 mycomputer slurmctld[30777]: slurmctld: Recovered information about 0 jobs
Feb 03 23:22:57 mycomputer slurmctld[30777]: slurmctld: select/cons_tres: part_data_create_array: select/cons_tres: preparing for 1 partitions
Feb 03 23:22:57 mycomputer slurmctld[30777]: slurmctld: Recovered state of 0 reservations
Feb 03 23:22:57 mycomputer slurmctld[30777]: slurmctld: read_slurm_conf: backup_controller not specified
Feb 03 23:22:57 mycomputer slurmctld[30777]: slurmctld: select/cons_tres: select_p_reconfigure: select/cons_tres: reconfigure
Feb 03 23:22:57 mycomputer slurmctld[30777]: slurmctld: select/cons_tres: part_data_create_array: select/cons_tres: preparing for 1 partitions
Feb 03 23:22:57 mycomputer slurmctld[30777]: slurmctld: Running as primary controller
Feb 03 23:22:57 mycomputer slurmctld[30777]: slurmctld: No parameter for mcs plugin, default values set
Feb 03 23:22:57 mycomputer slurmctld[30777]: slurmctld: mcs: MCSParameters = (null). ondemand set.
Feb 03 23:23:02 mycomputer slurmctld[30777]: slurmctld: SchedulerParameters=default_queue_depth=100,max_rpc_cnt=0,max_sched_time=2,partition_job_depth=0,sched_max_job_start=0,...
```

And it seems fine now.

My only guess is that it might have to do with the order in which `slurmdbd`, `slurmd`, and `slurmctld` services are started.  But I have been assuming that the default order is correct.  Perhaps this assumption is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defaults for slurmctld.service and slurmd.service are missing an ordering dependency on mysql.service. Let's add <s>one</s> two (Thanks @Ray for the clarification).

Create a file named `/etc/systemd/system/slurmctld.service.d/99-mysql-ordering-askubuntu-1502374.conf`:

```ini
[Unit]
# This will append the missing dependency to the defaults
After=slurmdbd.service
```

Create a file named `/etc/systemd/system/slurmd.service.d/99-mysql-ordering-askubuntu-1502374.conf`:

```ini
[Unit]
# This will append the missing dependency to the defaults
After=slurmctld.service
```

Then reboot.

Comment: Ah! It solved my problem, but with a slight adjustment.  I guessed the dependencies was more like `mysql` --> `slurmdbd` --> `slurmctld` --> `slurmd`.  And probably `slurmctld` was started before `slurmdbd`.  I added the above change, but to the last two in this chain (the first two appear fine).  And it worked!  I mistakenly thought that the order of these 4 were correct since I installed all of them as Ubuntu packages.  But, after your post, I checked the service files in `/usr/lib/systemd/system`, and this dependency wasn't mentioned.  I presume the above will survive upgrades?  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and teaching me the existence of the full set of 4 services, I added the second service, and realized I made a type with the first service. Yeah, Ubuntu is missing this dependency. Either it's intentional to allow them to run on different servers (unlikely because slurmdbd is after both mysql and mariadb, which are usually not installed together) or it's something that should be reported to Launchpad. Yes, things in `/etc/systemd/system` will survive updates, and is the recommended way to make changes to `/usr/lib/systemd/system`

Comment: Thanks for confirming I'm not crazy; I'll report it to Launchpad now and mention this page.  Based on the error messages, I spent some time playing with the database...thinking that was the problem.  `slurmdbd` is optional; without it, logs from jobs can be saved to a file.  That's probably why this doesn't affect many people; I have been using SLURM for many years but using file-based logging.  Thank you for teaching me more about `systemd` -- very helpful!